# Javascript - Function not activating?

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I've got a problem, I'm doing a program that updates a table on an html page to take an amount of dice rolls from a user, and then use an array to save the frequency of the numbers rolled and calculate the % they counted towards the total rolls of the user.

I seem to be having an issue however, my debugger shows that my prompt message is getting a value from the user, the array is initialized to 0, but the array does not seem to be updated via my function like it should. On top of that, I was testing updating the id table data sections to prepare them to display this data, but nothing seems to be showing.

Could anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong exactly? I know functions are usually activated by buttons, but I wasn't sure if the prompt button did this by default or not.

Any help is very appreciated, thank you!

UPDATE: With help from comments below the code is updated and the array is properly counting rolls. Woohoo! I still seem to be unable to get things to print over into table data tags on the html page however. I'll try placing it within the function and see if it helps.

```
 // Prompts the user to set the amount of desired rolls
var rolls = prompt("How many rolls of the dice do you want?", "");

// Declare and initialize the frequencies array to 0
var frequencies = new Array(13);

for (var index = 2; index <= 12; index++) 
    {
        frequencies[index] = 0;
    }

// Determine if user entered a valid number of rolls to make
if (rolls != null)
    {
        calculateRolls();
    }
else
    {
        rolls = prompt("You did not enter a valid number. Please try again.", "");
    }

// Rolls the die and stores the frequency of rolls
function calculateRolls() {

for (var i = 0; i < rolls; i++)
    {
        var roll1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var roll2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        sum = roll1 + roll2;
        frequencies[sum]++;
    }

}

// Display frequency and percentage of rolls on the main page
 var freq2 = document.getElementById("f2");
 freq2.innerHTML = "test array should go here";
```

Here's the HTML code as well, f2 being the id of the table data. I did my best to keep the format as my professor specified, so the table is a bit long.

```
......
<script src="Lab8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="mainDiv">

<h1>Lab 8: JavaScript</h1>

<!--This table holds the rolled data-->
<table>
<caption id="rollsCap">Frequency for x Rolls</caption>
<tr>
<th>Value Rolled</th>
<th>Frequency</th>
<th>Percentage</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>2</th>
<td id="f2"></td>
<td id="p2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>3</th>
<td id="f3"></td>
<td id="p3"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>4</th>
<td id="f4"></td>
<td id="p4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>5</th>
<td id="f5"></td>
<td id="p5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>6</th>
<td id="f6"></td>
<td id="p6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>7</th>
<td id="f7"></td>
<td id="p7"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>8</th>
<td id="f8"></td>
<td id="p8"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>9</th>
<td id="f9"></td>
<td id="p9"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>10</th>
<td id="f10"></td>
<td id="p10"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>11</th>
<td id="f11"></td>
<td id="p11"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>12</th>
<td id="f12"></td>
<td id="p12"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Percentages are rounded</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't know what's up with that `switch` statement. Why not just `frequencies[roll]++`?

Comment: You have two typos. Twice you spelled `frequencies` as `frequenices`

Comment: Oops, my bad. I'm terrible with typos in my code, thank you. Also, I had no clue you could do that with an array, thank you Phil. I'll give that a try

Comment: Just a note: the max value you can get for `roll` is **6**.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeah I just figured that out, I updated the code just now to use a second roll and combine them into a sum, which I then put as the array index. Worked perfectly. Thank you though, I can't believe I missed that

Comment: Where's your JS in relation to HTML? Is it possible that you try to change elements that have not been rendered yet?

Comment: @PM77-1 Just updated with the HTML now, the td does not actually contain anything, but I was not sure if that mattered or not since the td is present and given an id to work with

Comment: Either move your `<script>` to the bottom of the body or wrap all your code with `window.onload = { <all your stuff> };`. Currently your code runs before DOM is formed.

Comment: @PM77-1 Oh, I see what you mean now. My professor made it seem as if the script had to be declared in head to be in a separate js, but I tried moving the whole thing to the bottom of the body and it worked! Thank you!